# Chakra ui Styling multipart components not working - StyleProvider not found

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, chakra-ui

I'm trying to create style a multipart components as defined on [this doc](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/component-style#styling-multipart-components). But whatever I try I got the error

> ContextError: useStyles: `styles` is undefined. Seems you forgot to wrap the components in `<StylesProvider />`

**EDIT**: I also created a reproductible project:

- **Github**: https://github.com/ArthurGerbelot/issue-chakra-ui-styling-multipart-components
- **CodeSandbox**: https://codesandbox.io/p/github/ArthurGerbelot/issue-chakra-ui-styling-multipart-components/main

#### Code

This is a minimal reproduction example who give me the same error:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Box, BoxProps, createStylesContext, useMultiStyleConfig, useStyles } from "@chakra-ui/react";


export function TestContainer(props: any) {
  const { size, variant, children, ...rest } = props

  // 2. Consume the `useMultiStyleConfig` hook
  const styles = useMultiStyleConfig('TestContainer', { size, variant })
  const [StylesProvider] = createStylesContext('TestContainer');

  return (
    <Box __css={styles.testContainer} {...rest}>
      {/* 3. Mount the computed styles on `StylesProvider` */}
      <StylesProvider value={styles}>{children}</StylesProvider>
    </Box>
  )
}


export function TestChildren({
  ...props
}: BoxProps): JSX.Element {

  const styles = useStyles();
  return <Box __css={styles.testChildren} {...props} />

}
```

```js
import { createMultiStyleConfigHelpers } from "@chakra-ui/system";

const helpers = createMultiStyleConfigHelpers(['testContainer', 'testChildren'])

export const TestContainer = helpers.defineMultiStyleConfig({
  baseStyle: {
    testContainer: {
      border: '5px solid green',
    },
    testChildren: {
      color: 'blue',
    },
  },
});
```

#### Usage and error

I know that my style is well applied because if I try to use only the `TestContainer` I have a valid result:

```js
  <main>
    <TestContainer>
      Foo
    </TestContainer>
  </main>
```

[image: Working result]

But when I put the `TestChildren` on it I got the error on `useStyles()` line

```js
  <main>
    <TestContainer>
      <TestChildren>Bar</TestChildren>
    </TestContainer>
  </main>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is NOT to import `useStyles` from `"@chakra-ui/react"` like the Chakra UI guid say.

But instead the solution is to grab it from `createStylesContext`

```
  const [StylesProvider, useStyles] = createStylesContext('TestContainer');
```